# Does roxygen2 6.0.0 now require "@export" in the last line?

Tags: r, documentation, version, roxygen2

Prior to updating to `roxygen2` version 6.0.0, it appeared that the package supported using the `@export` tag not at the bottom of the function header in a package. For instance:

```
#' Title
#' @param foo
#' @return bar
#'
#' @export
#'
#' @seealso Other blah blah
```

The code above would build successfully with `roxygen2` properly filling out the namespace when using my installation of `roxygen2` version 5.0.1.
However, with the update this form of documentation would not work and `roxygen2` actively removes it from the *NAMESPACE.R*.

I could fix this by moving `@export` to the bottom

```
#' Title
#' @param foo
#' @return bar
#'
#' @seealso Other blah blah
#' @export
```

My question is whether this issue occurs by design? I can't see anything specifying this change to @export in the release notes: https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/releases/tag/v6.0.0

Was this always how `roxygen2` was supposed to work and the operation up until this point was unintended? Or is this a deliberate change?

**N.B.** Obviously making a full mwe for different versions is difficult, any suggestions on how to tackle this welcome

**EDIT:** After further testing I'm beginning to suspect that there is more to this than just roxygen. I am using the build and document shortcuts in rstudio, which I also update recently, and even stepping back to `roxygen2` version 5.0.1 stops me rebuilding the documentation of the old functions that used to work.

Comment: Was your problem solved? I think I have the same issue although `export` is always last.

Comment: Not really. This was part of a larger versioning issue I was bug fixing. In the end I settled on package version control using tools like packrat and checkpoint. The root cause of this and another bug still elude me, but reverting back to prior packages 'fixed' them.

Comment: If you are using RStudio: In my case the root cause was a missing check in Tools => Project options => Build Tools: Generate documentation.

Comment: Christoph, that wasn't mine, but is still a good point.

Comment: I don't have this issue. I can put @export anywhere and have the function show up in the NAMESPACE file. (and yes I'm on version 6.0.0)

Comment: So I guess part of the question is what command are you using to generate your documentation? I typically use `document` from devtools but using `roxygenize()` from roxygen2 directly gives me the same result (mainly that even if export isn't at the bottom it still includes it in the NAMESPACE file)

Comment: I typically use the rstudio keyboard shortcuts, which I believe call `roxygenize()`

Comment: Have you tried deleting the NAMESPACE file and then re-roxygenizing?

Answer (score 2):

In the backlog of the `Roxygen2` package there were couple of bugs  related to `@export` in 2017.

They are fixed now and cannot be reproduced:

- https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/574
- https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/656